# unpack variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template function:

```
template<typename R, typename... T>
void function(const std::string& id, R (*f)(T...)) {
    switch (sizeof...(T)) {
        case 0: f0compile<R>(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f)); break;
        case 1: f1compile<R, T>(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f)); break;
        case 2: f2compile<R, T1, T2>(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f)); break;
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I call these functions (f0compile, f1compile, f2compile) ? How can I write the "function" ?

```
template<typename R>
void f0compile(void (*f)()) {
    new F0<R>(f):
    ...
}
template<typename R, typename T>
void f1compile(void (*f)()) {
    new F1<R,T>(f);
    ...
}
template<typename R, typename T1, typename T2>
void f2compile(void (*f)()) {
    new F2<R,T1,T2>(f);
    ...
}
```

Thank you for help with these variadic template.

I add the implementation of F0 F1 F2:

```
template <typename R> struct F0 : F {
    F0(void (*_fn)()) : F(typeid(R))
        , fn(reinterpret_cast<R(*)()>(_fn))
    {}
    const void* f() { res = fn(); return &res; }
    R res; R (*fn)();
    void d() { delete this; }
};

template <typename R, typename T> struct F1 : F {
    F1(void (*_fn)(), F* _opd) : F(typeid(R))
        , fn(reinterpret_cast<R(*)(T)>(_fn))
        , opd(autocast<T>(_opd))
    {}
    const void* f() { res = fn(*(T*) opd->f()); return &res; }
    F* opd;
    R res; R (*fn)(T);
    void d() { opd->d(); delete this; }
};

template <typename R, typename T1, typename T2> struct F2 : F {
    F2(void (*_fn)(), F* _opd1, F* _opd2) : F(typeid(R))
        , fn(reinterpret_cast<R(*)(T1,T2)>(_fn))
        , opd1(autocast<T1>(_opd1))
        , opd2(autocast<T2>(_opd2))
    {}
    const void* f() { res = fn(*(T1*) opd1->f(), *(T2*) opd2->f()); return &res; }
    F* opd1; F* opd2;
    R res; R (*fn)(T1,T2);
    void d() { opd1->d(); opd2->d(); delete this; }
};
```

Thank you

```
struct F {
            F(const std::type_info& _type) : type(_type) {}
            virtual ~F() {}
            const std::type_info& type;
            virtual const void* f() = 0;
            virtual void d() = 0;
        };
```

Added class F . It rapresent each function / operand on the stack

```
template <typename T> struct Opd : F {
        Opd(T _opd) : F(typeid(T)), res(_opd) { }
        const void* f() { return &res; }
        T res;
        void d() { delete this; }
    };
```

Added class Opd . It represent a specific operand on the stack.

The real program is this (simplified):

```
double foo(double op1, double op2) {
    return op1 + op2;
}

#include <functional>
#include <stack>
#include <type_traits>

class Expression {
    public:
        struct F {
            F(const std::type_info& _type) : type(_type) {}
            virtual ~F() {}
            const std::type_info& type;
            virtual const void* f() = 0;
            virtual void d() = 0;
        };
    public:
        Expression() : m_cexpr(NULL) {}
        ~Expression() {
            if (m_cexpr) m_cexpr->d();
        }
        // function
        template<typename R, typename... T> void function(R (*f)(T...), void (*compile)(void (*)(), std::stack<F*>&)) {
            m_f = std::make_pair(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f), compile);
        }
        template<typename R, typename T1, typename T2> static void f2compile(void (*f)(), std::stack<F*>& s) {
            auto opd2 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            auto opd1 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            s.push(new F2<R,T1,T2>(f, opd1, opd2));
        }
        void compile() {
            if (m_cexpr) m_cexpr->d();
            std::stack<F*> s;
            s.push(new Opd<double>(1));
            s.push(new Opd<double>(2));
            m_f.second(m_f.first, s);
            m_cexpr = s.top();
            s.pop();
            assert(s.empty());
        }
        void* execute() { 
            return const_cast<void*>(m_cexpr->f()); 
        }
        const std::type_info& type() { 
            return m_cexpr->type; 
        }
    private:
        F* m_cexpr;
        std::pair<void (*)(), void (*)(void (*)(), std::stack<F*>&)> m_f;
        template <typename T> struct Opd : F {
            Opd(T _opd) : F(typeid(T)), res(_opd) {}
            const void* f() { return &res; }
            T res;
            void d() { delete this; }
        };
        template <typename R, typename T1, typename T2> struct F2 : F {
            F2(void (*_fn)(), F* _opd1, F* _opd2) : F(typeid(R))
                , fn(reinterpret_cast<R(*)(T1,T2)>(_fn))
                , opd1(_opd1)
                , opd2(_opd2)
            {}
            const void* f() { res = fn(*(T1*) opd1->f(), *(T2*) opd2->f()); return &res; }
            F* opd1; F* opd2;
            R res; R (*fn)(T1,T2);
            void d() { opd1->d(); opd2->d(); delete this; }
        };
};

TEST_CASE("expression") {
    Expression e;
    e.function(foo, e.f2compile<double, double, double>);
    e.compile();
    e.execute();
    REQUIRE(e.type() == typeid(double));
    REQUIRE(*static_cast<double*>(e.execute()) == 3);
}
```

And my problem is how write better code c++11 using variadic template. How write a function "fNcompile" and a function "FN" with variadic template.

Comment: And what about the `F` class (struct?)? In your example you call (by example) without `odp*` parameters.

Comment: A little doubt: maybe you can make what you want simply with a lambda function?

Comment: Do `f0compile`, `f1compile`, ..., `F0`, `F1`, ... need to have those separate names, or could they also be variadic templates `fcompile` and `F_n`?

Comment: The constructor of `F1` takes two arguments, but you're passing just one in `new F1<R,T>(f);`

Comment: f0compile, f1complile could be variadic template fNcompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the specific question, below are variadic `FN` and `fNcompile` as close as possible to your existing code.  First, though, since you said you're working in C++11, we'll need an equivalent of `std::make_index_sequence` from C++14. Here's a simple one. You can search for others that are smarter about being less likely to hit compiler template limitations...

```
namespace cxx_compat {
    template <typename T, T... Values>
    struct integer_sequence {
        static constexpr std::size_t size() const
        { return sizeof...(Values); }
    };

    template <typename T, T Smallest, T... Values>
    struct make_integer_sequence_helper {
        static_assert(Smallest > 0,
            "make_integer_sequence argument must not be negative");
        using type = typename make_integer_sequence_helper<
            T, Smallest-1, Smallest-1, Values...>::type;
    };
    template <typename T, T... Values>
    struct make_integer_sequence_helper<T, 0, Values...> {
        using type = integer_sequence<T, Values...>;
    };

    template <typename T, T N>
    using make_integer_sequence =
        typename make_integer_sequence_helper<T, N>::type;

    template <std::size_t... Values>
    using index_sequence = integer_sequence<std::size_t, Values...>;

    template <std::size_t N>
    using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>;

    template <typename... T>
    using index_sequence_for = make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>;
} // end namespace cxx_compat
```

And now, the actual `FN` and `fNcompile`:

```
template <typename R, typename ...T> struct FN : F {
private:
    template <typename T>
    using any_to_Fstar = F*;
public:
    FN(void (*_fn)(), any_to_Fstar<T> ... _opd) : F(typeid(R))
        , fn(reinterpret_cast<R(*)(T...)>(_fn))
        , opd{_opd...}
    {}
    FN(R (*_fn)(T...)) : F(typeid(R)), fn(_fn), opd() {}
    const void* f() {
        f_helper(cxx_compat::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
        return &res;
    }
    std::array<F*, sizeof...(T)> opd;
    R res; R (*fn)(T...);
    void d() {
        for (F* o : opd)
            o->d();
        delete this;
    }
private:
    template <std::size_t... Inds>
    void f_helper(cxx_compat::index_sequence<Inds...>)
    { res = fn(*(T*) opd[Inds]->f() ...); }
};

template<typename R, typename... T>
static void fNcompile(void (*f)(), std::stack<F*>& s) {
    auto* f_obj = new FN<R, T...>(f);
    for (std::size_t ind = sizeof...(T); ind > 0;) {
        f_obj->opd[--ind] = s.top();
        s.pop();
    }
    s.push(f_obj);
}
```

What's going on:

- To actually call the function pointer, we need access to a number of function arguments at the same time, so to replace the named members `opd1`, `opd2` with a number of `F*` pointers determined by template instantiation, we use a `std::array<F*, sizeof...(T)>`, since `sizeof...(T)` is the number of argument types provided to the template.
- For compatibility with the `F2` constructor you declared, `any_to_Fstar<T> ... _opd` declares a number of constructor parameters to match the number of `T` template arguments, all with the same type `F*`. (But now `fNcompile` uses the additional constructor taking just the function pointer instead, and sets the array members afterward.)
- To get at these pointers and pass them all to `fn` in one expression, we need to expand some sort of variadic pack. Here's where `index_sequence` comes in:

  - `index_sequence_for<T...>` is a type alias for `index_sequence` with a sequence of numbers counting up from zero as template arguments.  For example, if `sizeof...(T)` is 4, then `index_sequence_for<T...>` is `index_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3>`.
  - `f` just calls a private function `f_helper`, passing it an object of that `index_sequence_for<T...>` type.
  - The compiler can deduce the template argument list for `f_helper` from matching the `index_sequence` types: `Inds...` must be that same sequence of numbers counting up from zero.
  - In the `f_helper` body, the expression `fn(*(T*) opd[Inds]->f() ...)` is instantiated by expanding both the template parameter packs `T` and `Inds` to get one list of function arguments for calling `fn`.

However, use of `void` pointers and `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous and rarely actually necessary in C++.  There's almost always a safer way using templates.  So I'd redesign this to be something more like:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <stack>

namespace cxx_compat {
    // Define integer_sequence and related templates as above.

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ... args)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
} // end namespace cxx_compat

class bad_expression_type : public std::logic_error
{
public:
    bad_expression_type(const std::type_info& required,
                        const std::type_info& passed)
        : logic_error("bad_argument_type"),
          required_type(required),
          passed_type(passed) {}
    const std::type_info& required_type;
    const std::type_info& passed_type;
};

class Expression
{
public:
    class F
    {
    public:
        F() noexcept = default;
        F(const F&) = delete;
        F& operator=(const F&) = delete;
        virtual ~F() = default;
        virtual const std::type_info& type() const noexcept = 0;
        virtual void compile(std::stack<std::unique_ptr<F>>&) = 0;

        template <typename R>
        R call_R() const;
    };
    using F_ptr = std::unique_ptr<F>;
    using F_stack = std::stack<F_ptr>;

    template <typename R>
    class Typed_F : public F
    {
    public:
        const std::type_info& type() const noexcept override
        { return typeid(R); }
        virtual R call() const = 0;
    };

    // Accepts any callable: function pointer, lambda, std::function,
    // other class with operator().
    template <typename R, typename... T, typename Func,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<
            decltype(std::declval<const Func&>()(std::declval<T>()...)),
            R>::value>::type>
    void function(Func func)
    {
        store_func<R, T...>(std::move(func));
    }
    // Overload for function pointer that does not need explicit
    // template arguments:
    template <typename R, typename... T>
    void function(R (*fptr)(T...))
    {
        store_func<R, T...>(fptr);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void constant(const T& value)
    {
        store_func<T>([value](){ return value; });
    }

    void compile(F_stack& stack)
    {
        m_cexpr->compile(stack);
    }

private:
    template <typename Func, typename R, typename... T>
    class F_Impl : public Typed_F<R>
    {
    public:
        F_Impl(Func func) : m_func(std::move(func)) {}
        void compile(F_stack& stack) override {
            take_args_helper(stack, cxx_compat::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
        }
        R call() const override {
            return call_helper(cxx_compat::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
        }
    private:
        template <typename Arg>
        int take_one_arg(std::unique_ptr<Typed_F<Arg>>& arg, F_stack& stack)
        {
            auto* fptr = dynamic_cast<Typed_F<Arg>*>(stack.top().get());
            if (!fptr)
                throw bad_expression_type(
                    typeid(Arg), stack.top()->type());
            arg.reset(fptr);
            stack.top().release();
            stack.pop();
            return 0;
        }
        template <std::size_t... Inds>
        void take_args_helper(F_stack& stack, cxx_compat::index_sequence<Inds...>)
        {
            using int_array = int[];
            (void) int_array{ take_one_arg(std::get<Inds>(m_args), stack) ..., 0 };
        }
        template <std::size_t... Inds>
        R call_helper(cxx_compat::index_sequence<Inds...>) const {
            return m_func(std::get<Inds>(m_args)->call()...);
        }

        Func m_func;
        std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Typed_F<T>>...> m_args;
    };

    template <typename R, typename... T, typename Func>
    void store_func(Func func)
    {
        m_cexpr = cxx_compat::make_unique<F_Impl<Func, R, T...>>(
            std::move(func));
    }

    F_ptr m_cexpr;
};

template <typename R>
R Expression::F::call_R() const
{
    auto* typed_this = dynamic_cast<const Typed_F<R>*>(this);
    if (!typed_this)
        throw bad_expression_type(typeid(R), type());
    return typed_this->call();
}

TEST_CASE("expression") {
    Expression a;
    a.constant(1.0);
    Expression b;
    b.constant(2.0);
    Expression c;
    c.function(+[](double x, double y) { return x+y; });

    Expression::F_stack stack;
    a.compile(stack);
    REQUIRE(stack.size() == 1);
    b.compile(stack);
    REQUIRE(stack.size() == 2);
    c.compile(stack);
    REQUIRE(stack.size() == 1);

    REQUIRE(stack.top() != nullptr);
    REQUIRE(stack.top()->type() == typeid(double));
    REQUIRE(stack.top()->call_R<double>() == 3.0);
}
```

It would also be possible, but a bit tricky, to support reference and `const` variations of the argument and result types, for example, using a `std::string(*)()` function as an argument to an `unsigned int(*)(const std::string&)` function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need the variadic template.  Instead:

```
template<typename R>
void fcompile(void (*f)()) {
    new F0<R>(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f));
    ...
}
template<typename R, typename T>
void fcompile(void (*f)(T)) {
    new F1<R,T>(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f));
    ...
}
template<typename R, typename T1, typename T2>
void fcompile(void (*f)(T1, T2)) {
    new F1<R,T1,T2>(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f));
    ...
}
```

Now you can call `fcompile<some_type>(some_func)` for any `some_type` and any nullary/unary/binary `some_func` which returns void.

Comment: In my example I have to call function with max 2 arguments, but in production I have function with 8 arguments.

Comment: @MarioRollino - do you mean "max 2 **template** arguments"?  The `T1, T2, ...` arguments?

Comment: I want solve my problem for fcompile with 3 4 5 ... n arguments, only by write another case: case 8: f2compile<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(f)); break;

Comment: @MarioRollino - it seems to me that you don't need the `switch` and the `case`s (see the John's answer); the bigger problem I see are the `Fn` classes; I'm trying to understand if it's necessary to develop different classes or if you can do all in a variadic class. But you should give more details (the `F` base class; how the `odp*` parameters are passed to the `Fn` constructors, etc.

Comment: @MarioRollino: Your comment says you can call `f2compile<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>` but that is not true--`f2compile` only takes three template type arguments.  I'm surprised you haven't noticed that.

Comment: i want write f8compile